# jQuery slide out animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a slide out bar for a project I am working on and I am having a hard time getting an animation to work.

My Goal is to have it slide out from left to right not appear from the top like it is now.

Below is my jQuery code as well as my jsfidde

Thanks in advance
George

http://jsfiddle.net/tXye8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $button = $('#sideoutButton');
var $contain = $('#slideoutContain');
var containWidth = $('#slideoutContain').width();

//Hide the box
$contain.hide();

//Hide or show the container on button click
$button.click(function(){
    if ($contain.is(":visible")) {
        $contain.hide();
        $button.css("left", 0);
    }
    else {
        $contain.show(400, buttonMove());
    }
});

function buttonMove(){
    $button.css("left", function(value) {
        return 0 + containWidth;
    });
}
  });
```

Comment: You should be using `.animate()` with transitions.

Comment: I see that you're new to SO. It would be kind of you to accept whichever answer has been most helpful. Otherwise, comment to let us know how the question can be better answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know how wide it's supposed to be, you can achieve this with CSS:

```
#mycontainer {
    width: 0;
    transition: width 400ms ease;
}

#mycontainer.expand {
    width: 400px; //or whatever your width is
}
```

and just use JS/jQuery to toggle a class on `#mycontainer`